# GCS - DataCorruption: Checksum mismatch while downloading

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using python's `google-cloud` client to download a file from Google Cloud Storage (GCS), getting the following error:

```
File "/deploy/app/scanworker/storagehandler/gcshandler.py" line 62 in download_object 
blob.download_to_file(out_file)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py" line 464 in download_to_file self._do_download(transport, file_obj, download_url, headers)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py" line 418 in _do_download
download.consume(transport)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/download.py" line 169 in consume    

self._write_to_stream(result)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/download.py" line 132 in _write_to_stream [args] [locals]
raise common.DataCorruption(response, msg)


DataCorruption: Checksum mismatch while downloading:

https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/<my-bucket>/o/<my-object>?alt=media

The X-Goog-Hash header indicated an MD5 checksum of:

fdn2kKmS4J6LCN6gfmEUVQ==

but the actual MD5 checksum of the downloaded contents was:

C9+ywW2Dap0gEv5gHoR1UQ==
```

I use the following code to download the blob from GCS:

```python
bucket_name = '<some-bucket>'
service_account_key = '<path to json credential file>'
with open(service_account_key, 'r') as f:
    keyfile = json.load(f)
    project_id = keyfile['project_id']

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_key)
client = storage.Client(project=project_id,
                         credentials=credentials)
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

blob_name = '<name of blob>'
download_path = "./foo.obj"
blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
with open(download_path, "w") as out_file:
    blob.download_to_file(out_file) # it fails here
```

Some info:

- Using python3
- running in a Ubuntu 16.04 Docker container in Kubernetes
- using google-cloud client library version 0.27.0 downloaded with pika

Also, I cannot seem to reproduce the error on my local desktop, downloading the same files that failed from my Docker container.

Is this an error with the client library? Or could it be a network issue?
Tried downloading different files, all giving the same error from Kubernetes. The same code has been running for months without problem, only seeing this error now.

**Edit:**

Rebuilding the Docker container from the exact same code as before  seems to have fixed the problem. I'm still curious to what caused the error in the first place though.

**Edit 2:**
We use circleci to deploy the webapp to production. Now it looks like the image built on circleci fails, while building it locally does seem to work. Since it's contained in a Docker container this is really weird, should not matter where we build it from?

**Edit 3:**
Logging in to the very same container in kubernetes giving the error above, I tried running `gsutil cp gs:/<bucket>/<blob-name> foo.obj`
This ran without any problem

Comment: Does the object you're downloading have its content-encoding set to gzip? If so this is a problem in a recent change we made to the google-cloud-resumable-media library, to add checksumming support (but that currently checksums the gunzipped content, while the service sends the checksum for the gzipped content). We're working on a fix now.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz : I use the same library google.cloud.storage i.e google-cloud==0.25.0 in an app engine app. I also added google-resumable-media==0.2.3 to my dependencies list to deploy on app engine.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz : Whenever the app tries to download a file larger than 32 MB i get the same DataCorruption: Checksum mismatch while downloading:
error.

I understand the files larger than 32 mb cant be processed in app engine. does this  mean the storage library internally tries to gzip files that are larger than 32MB and hence i run into the checksum comparison error ? this is what im doing  :   client = storage.Client(project='myproj')
        bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = Blob(file_name, bucket)
        file = blob.download_as_string()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment by Mike: This was an issue with version 0.3.0 of `google-resumable-media` library. (See the issue here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-resumable-media-python/issues/34)

Specifying `google-resumable-media==0.2.3` in our pip's `requirements.txt` did the job!

The reason the error did not appear in the Docker image built from my desktop was that I had cached images with the old version of `google-resumable-media`.

Comment: I believe the librayr is google-resumable-media and not google-cloud*-resumable-media ?

Comment: Now I'm using google-resumable-media 2.4.1 and got basically the same error. Error message here https://github.com/zpz/upathlib/issues/116 Any ideas??